# Antívirus Kaspersky bloqueando Modal Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

Meu antivirus bloqueando ao abrir modal, o modal nem é exibido direito.

Segue código:

**Evento click:**

```
$("#cartoes_click").click(function () {
    $('.ModalContent_Cartoes').load("/Payment/_Cartoes_Fisica", function () {
        $('#myModal_Cartoes').modal('show');
    });
});
```

**Controller:**

```
[HttpGet]
public PartialViewResult _Cartoes_Fisica()
{
   return PartialView();
}
```

**PartialView:**

Aqui eu tenho um pedacinho de código javascript, que antivírus bloqueia:

```
var teste1 = "Número do cartão inválido";
```

Ou

```
vat teste2 = "Invalid card number";
```

Com esses códigos acima, Kaspersky bloqueia modal bootstrap, se eu fizer colocar string assim: `var teste1 = qualquer coisa aqui`, o antivírus não bloqueia.

Quando eu clico no botão para abrir modal, dá essas mensagens abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Isso quer dizer que um antivírus tem uma palavra reservada ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Amigo, kaspersky é um ótimo antívirus... eu não uso antívirus pq eu mesmo sou meu próprio antívirus, mas o seu caso é bem estranho, nunca vi algo assim.

Provavelmente, o antívirus esta bloqueado por que o seu site não tem "httpS" mesmo estando em localhost, pois agora site sem HTTPS, são considerado bem mais inseguros, até por que agora existe certificado SSL de graça.

Tenta subir o código em uma hosedagem ssl, ou... só pra não ficar se irritando com o antívirus, coloque isso como um falso positivo.

Comment: Quer dizer se eu ativar ssl, o antivírus não tem mais capacidade de bloquear ?

Comment: O cara tem toda razão, ativei o SSL aqui, e funcionou.

Comment: obrigado a quem clicou na seta de baixo e me negativou